# Connecting Android Development Board to Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: android, omap

I recently received a development board from TI which is running Android on OMAP 3621 and I am trying to connect it to my machine through USB. The board says Connected in Debugging Mode.

```
system@system-laptop:~$ lsusb |grep Google
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 18d1:0001 Google Inc.
```

On the board the USB debugging is ON and so is accept from Unknown Source.
My `.rule` file for udev is as follows

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct} =="0001",SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
```

After this I restarted udev and adb servers using sudo.  Still it does not detect the dev board, but it detects my HTC Desire.  I have tried Googling but in vain, and I have even tried adding the vendor ID in the adb_usb.ini file but still in vain.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Adb does not yet know about the vendor id, so it will not connect to your device.

You only have to add the id to the file ~/.android/adb.ini and then it will work.

It should be a plain text file with all vendor id's of all android devices you work with listed one per line. If you only want your TI-board it should contain the single line:

> 0x18d1

If this does not work (it should, but...) try a google search on adb.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You should grep Texas Instruments and use that ID I guess